# How to mark programmatically method that will be handle by an aspect method?

Tags: java, spring

I have an aspect

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ImportAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(com.backend.annotations.Import)")
    public void handleImport(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //some logic
    }

}
```

Is there is a way, maybe by a beanPostProcessor mark another component's class method that will be handled by the aspect's method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Mark it how? The methods are already "marked" with your @Import annotation.

Comment: @Michael I mean to say to spring programmatically do same like this @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(com.backend.annotations.Import)")

Comment: Something like this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-prog

Comment: @Michael Something like addAspectLogic(bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test"), ImportAspect.class.getDeclaredMethod("handleImport"))